# tabItem appears when tabName is put in as string, but not as variable in R SHINY

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a dashboard with a different body appearing for different tabs. However, the below code does not work. While tabs are created, nothing appears in the tabs. If I change tabName to a string (ex. menuItem(name_dataset[1], tabName = "data1")), the right body contents appear in each tab.

Why is this? Why can I not use a variable for tabName instead of just raw string?

```
#SHINY DASHBOARD: UI 
header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem(name_datasets[1], tabName = name_datasets[1]),
    menuItem(name_datasets[2], tabName = name_datasets[2])
    )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
    #First tab
        tabItem(tabName = name_datasets[1], h2(name_datasets[1])),

    #Second tab
    tabItem(tabName = name_datasets[2], h2(name_datasets[2]))
    )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)
```

Comment: It should work like this if `name_datasets` is a vector/list. What is the content of `name_datasets`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that your `name_datasets` vector includes strings with either spaces or some other reserved character. The `tabName` argument (whether supplied directly or not) should be a simple and unique key, so it shouldn't contain spaces, ampersands, percentages, etc...

You can verify this works without "weird" characters:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

name_datasets <- c(a = "letter_a1", b = "letter_b2")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
    menuItem(name_datasets[1], tabName = name_datasets[1]),
    menuItem(name_datasets[2], tabName = name_datasets[2])
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = name_datasets[1], h2(name_datasets[1])),
    tabItem(tabName = name_datasets[2], h2(name_datasets[2]))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), sidebar, body)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, if you do want to display spaces or dollar signs or something "weird" to the end-user, you can still do that (since `tabName` is only really used internally). For example, this is a very similar app to the last one, but you'll notice that even though the `tabName`s are very simple (`"a"` and `"b"`), what is displayed to the user both in the sidebar and in the main body is a lot more complex:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

name_datasets <- c(a = "letter $ % a1", b = "letter b2 % $")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
    menuItem(name_datasets[1], tabName = names(name_datasets)[1]),
    menuItem(name_datasets[2], tabName = names(name_datasets)[2])
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = names(name_datasets)[1], h2(name_datasets[1])),
    tabItem(tabName = names(name_datasets)[2], h2(name_datasets[2]))
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), sidebar, body)
server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```